# How to reference a field from an object defined in wrapper class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I need to access fields from objects I declared as variables in a wrapper class. I tried to refer to them using dot notation, however the following form is not working:

`wrapper.object.field`

Class

```
public class awardsClassExperiment {
    //Initialize objects
    public class Submission {
        public Recipient__c recipient {get;set;}
        public Scholarship_Award__c scholarship {get;set;}
        
        //Constructor for wrapper class
        public Submission(){
            this.recipient = new recipient__c();
            this.scholarship = new Scholarship_Award__c();
        }
    }
    
    //Get set
    public List<Submission> submissions {get;set;}
    public Submission currentSubmission {get;set;}
    
    //Initialize list
    public awardsClassExperiment(){
        this.submissions = new List<Submission>();
        this.currentSubmission = new Submission();

    }


    //Add scholarship to list
    public PageReference Add_Recipient(){

        //Add to master list(wrapper class)
        //Fields
        this.currentSubmission = new Submission();   
        //The following 2 lines are the issue
        this.currentSubmission.recipient.Name = Submission.recipient.name;
        this.currentSubmission.recipient.Last_Name__c = Submission.recipient.Last_Name__c;
        
        this.submissions.add(this.currentSubmission);
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting `Variable does not exist: Submission.Recipient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `Submission.recipient.name` would only work if you defined a static member `recipient` in the class `Submission`. But you only have an instance member `recipient`, which is correctly referenced on the left side by `this.currentSubmission.recipient.Name`.

If you wish to assign a `Name` and `Last_Name__c` to a freshly-created Submission object,  you should clarify where that Name and Last Name really come from. Even if class Submission had some such static members, the `Add_Recipient()` would always be adding the *same* Name and Last Name into `submissions`.

I'm not sure what your setup is. Maybe you could pass that information as parameters to the `Add_Recipient()` function?

Comment: Thanks this is a controller behind a VF webform which gathers input dynamically from the user. So it is different each time.

Comment: I'm mostly Apex + Aura + LWC, and had only marginal contact with VF, but the inputs of a VF page are normally bound to fields in the instance of the corresponding Apex Controller. Meaning, whichever Apex Controller houses the function which gets called for your `<apex:commandButton action>`, should be able to retrieve the VF form inputs (Name, LastName) and then pass them to `Add_Recipient()` in `awardsClassExperiment` as parameters. Those parameters could then serve as the source info that you give to the `currentSubmission`.